# Регулярные выражения для проверки id

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Прошу извенить, но я чайник в регулярках. Сижу изучаю мануал и серавно не доходит

```
^[iI]{1}[dD]{1}([1-9]*)$
```

Нужно чтоб не пропускал ID+Число
К примеру
id123
Id123
ID123
iD132
id
123
Помогите пожайлуста

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Я делаю preg_match() Вот мне надо чтоб он ловил вышеперечисленные надписи

Answer (score 1):

Так как есть две группы, которые могут присутствовать независимо друг от друга стоит их разделить и использовать квантификатор `?` который указывает, что группа может повторяться один раз либо отсутствовать

```
(id)?(\d+)?
```

Чтобы проверка была не зависима от регистра, необходимо использовать флаг `i` (ignorecase)

```
/(id)?(\d+)?/i
```

Возможно можно обойтись одной группой

```
/(id)?\d*/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Это для поиска

```
id123
Id123
ID123
iD132
id
```

отделённых пробелами: `\s?([Ii][Dd])(\d+)?\s`